# OpenCL : kernel read interpolated value from a INT_16 image

Tags: image, opencl, interpolation

I'm using a kernel which take a **INT_16** image as input.

I try to read interpolated values from this image using a sampler declared with **CLK_FILTER_LINEAR**.

I have correct values using the **read_imagei** method : for example, if I read between a "200" pixel and a "300" pixel, I got "220" result (depending on the reading coordinates)

Now I try to read using **read_imagef** values to get more precise values :

- image is declared as **CL_SNORM_INT16**
- sampler is declared using **CLK_FILTER_LINEAR**
- read values are multiplied by **32767.0f** (to convert from the [-1.0;+1.0] CL_SNORM_INT16 range to the INT_16 range)

Here, I can read the same values as before (using read_imagei).

But I never get values like "220.56" or "220.76", I always get rounded values.
Just like if the internal interpolation on the GPU have been computed using INT_16 registers, not floating point register.

I didn't see enything in the OpenCL spec about the way that interpolation between INT_16 values should be computed.

**Question :**

Is it normal to always get rounded values and never floating point values when using **read_imagef** from a **CL_SNORM_INT16** image sampled with **CLK_FILTER_LINEAR** mode ?

(I need to use INT_16 image to limit memory usage, but I would like to have floatint point precision in interpolation results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is within the OpenCL specification, though it may differ between implementations. Relevant part of the specification is the note at the very end of [Addressing and Filter Modes](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html#addressing-and-filter-modes), which also includes a workaround to get your desired behavior:

> For all other sampler combinations of normalized or unnormalized coordinates, filter and addressing modes, the relative error or precision of the addressing mode calculations and the image filter operation are not defined by this revision of the OpenCL specification. To ensure a minimum precision of image addressing and filter calculations across any OpenCL device, for these sampler combinations, developers should unnormalize the image coordinate in the kernel and implement the linear filter in the kernel with appropriate calls to read_image{f|i|ui} with a sampler that uses unnormalized coordinates, filter mode set to CLK_FILTER_NEAREST, addressing mode set to CLK_ADDRESS_NONE, CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE or CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP, and finally performing the interpolation of color values read from the image to generate the filtered color value.